# Is ViewPager really what I need for this scenario?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

**APPLICATION IDEA:** Idea is simple. When application is launched it will connect to web service which will return number of rows in particular column in database, then it will retrive data from first row and display in activity. When user interacts with its finger, left or right (e.g swiping through pages), it needs to load next (or previous) row from database. 
Please check following picture you may understand better.

[image]

**PROBLEM:** Since I'm new in Android I would like to know which scenario best fits my needs. I actually need to load data from database when user swipes and show this on my current screen.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:** I already made my "homework" and I searched google for my problem. I used implementation of **ViewPager** class with **PagerAdapter** class. But when I swipe on the next page nothing is showed ( Yes I used AsynTask and I sucessfully pulled data to my device), but instead is showed on the NEXT page.

So I need to know if ViewPager is really what I need? Do I need to use ViewPager together with FragmentPagerAdapter so that my text will load exactly when my page is showed?

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` suits this scenario well.

Note that `ViewPager` by default loads the next and previous pages while the current page is being shown (off-screen page limit 1). Your adapter likely has some bugs that make it pull data for the wrong page. To get help with them, please post a more specific question.